# Implementing Bell LaPadula for users and services

Tags: security

My application consists of a key distribution center, T, some users, U, and some services, S. T is implementing a Bell Lapadula politics, where users are the subjects and services are the objects. Here is what I don't understand:

1. Users have security levels and services have classifications. Every site I've searched, both, subjects and objects had security levels which could be compared. I don't know how to compare a security level with a classification. This is a constraint made by my teacher.
2. I've read something about trusted subjects having, both, a security maximum level and a current maximum level. After lowering its current level, does it keep the confidential information gathered from the upper level? How can this be safe if it does?! What is the default current level?
3. *property says that a subject, s, mustn't be able to write down to an object o1 if it can read up from an object o2. Does this mean I have to check all the objects on a higher level than s and if there is no read up than I should let s write in o1? Some sites lack first condition.
4. I don't see how this model fits to my problem cause users can only access services. There is no read or write. Or there is? Please light me up.

These might make you believe it's just nonsense, but I'm pretty poor at modelling this problem and these issues don't let me moving on to the next step. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

1. For rules made up by teachers, you have to refer to the teacher, the teacher's lecture notes, or the text book to understand what they're talking about. The 'security levels' and 'classifications' have to be comparable at some point. However, it might be that a user is classified as 'Technical Staff' or 'Clerical Staff', and these lead to Technical Staff can read levels 6-9 (but can only write at level 7), Clerical Staff can read levels 3-7 (but can only write at level 4), etc. Different services might have appropriate levels. I doubt if the numbers I invented are a sensible policy.
2. 'No read up; no write down'. A user can read data a security levels up to and including their current level, but can only write data at their current level. This means that data from a higher security level cannot be written at a lower level (where, presumably, people who are not authorized at the higher level could read it, thus breaching the security policies).

I think this also explains 3, and 4.  A user can only write to the current maximum read level. If they could write at a lower level, information would seep out from a higher security level to a lower security level, which is precisely what you want to prevent.

People can't read the bits on the disk; a service (program) always does the reading for them, subject to the policies implied by security levels and classifications of the objects (think files) that are accessed and the service and person accessing them.

Comment: What you're saying about writing only to the current level is the strong star property, an alternative to the star property.

Comment: The simple security or ss-property:
- For any (S,O, A) ∈ b, if A includes observation, then level(S)
must dominate level(O)
- E.g., an unclassiﬁed user cannot read a top-secret document( pretty clear)
• The star security or *-property:
- If a subject can observe O1 and modify O2, then level(O2)
dominates level(O1)
So it doesn't mention level(s): it doesn't matter if it's above O1, O2 or not as I can see from this.

Comment: OK; it is a number of years since I last read the Bell LaPadula paper; it isn't particularly easy. There must be security textbooks which cover it. I certainly didn't go look up the *-property.